# pandas concat but take duplicate key rows from left df

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Hopefully a simple one. I have 2 dfs as per below. I would like to fill in the blank spaces with df2 for any PORT,MTH combo that is in df1. I can't just concat and drop_duplicates as the values may not match and I want to keep my df1 entry if it exists.

DF1

```
MTH,PORT,value
201503,PORT1,0.302
201504,PORT1,0.231
201505,PORT1,0.833
201502,PORT2,0.35
201503,PORT2,0.734
201504,PORT2,0.755
201505,PORT2,0.257
```

DF2

```
MTH,PORT,value
201501,PORT1,0.4033
201502,PORT1,0.2733
201503,PORT1,0.1412
201501,PORT2,0.324
201502,PORT2,0.6593
201503,PORT2,0.276
```

So for the above, I would like to create 1 df and for PORT1 have the 201501 and 201502 entries from DF2 since DF1 doesn't have them, but keep the rest of the DF1 PORT entries. For PORT2 we would just bring in 201501 entry.

In words it is a concat but if keys (mth,port) are duplicates, take from left df.

Thanks in advance

expected output

```
MTH,PORT,value
201501,PORT1,0.4033
201502,PORT1,0.2733
201503,PORT1,0.302
201504,PORT1,0.231
201505,PORT1,0.833
201501,PORT2,0.324
201502,PORT2,0.35
201503,PORT2,0.734
201504,PORT2,0.755
201505,PORT2,0.257
```

Comment: kindly post expected output

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(['MTH', 'PORT'])`, should work?

Comment: in the case of PORT1 above, the PORT1 201501 value is different in both dfs, so which will it drop? It's very important that I keep the df1 value where it is available.

Comment: will post expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(['MTH','PORT'])
```

Comment: I've tried this and set keep='first' to keep the value from df1 where there is a dupe. This doesn't feel very robust but seems to work for what I need. thank you.